Can I extend JPARepository to get all the default crud endpoints and configure my own custom @RestController?
I'm creating a sample library app with a Spring Boot backend. Currently, my DAO classes just extend JPARepository so that I automatically get access to basic CRUD HTTP endpoints for these entities.
For example: public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>
Now, I want to add a @RestController following this tutorial for Auth0 integration with Spring Boot. On a previous project, when I started to add custom controllers, I lost the use of all the basic CRUD endpoints that extending JpaRepository got me. At this point I fell under the impression that the two couldn't be used together, however I just tried the same thing again and now I'm able to use both the generated endpoints and my custom controller.
So, can anyone clear up why I can or can't or shouldn't do this?
Here is a sample of my @RestController:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LibraryController {
    private LibraryService libraryService;

    @Autowired
    public LibraryController(LibraryService libraryService) {
        this.libraryService = libraryService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/books")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Book>> getBooks(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0", value = "page", required = false) int page,
                                   @RequestParam(defaultValue = "5", value = "size", required = false) int pageSize) {
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize);
        Page books = libraryService.findAllBooksPageable(paging);
        return new ResponseEntity<Page<Book>>(books, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


The JPA Repository with its standard query methods created by Spring and the controller annotated with @RestController are two completely different things, serving two completely different purposes. They have nothing in common and don't interfere in any way.
